# Grafana chart title location to maximize available chart area: Title in chart area?

Tags: grafana

I have a grafana dashboard with several time-history charts above each other.  Signals are grouped by topic and scaling.  The title of each chart is nice to have, but they take up valuable screen space making the plots smaller and hard to read.

The titles can be removed (use a blank title), and then the plot fills the whole space.  Clicking at the top of the chart still gets the context menu to edit the chart, etc.  That would be good, But the title is gone (top plot in picture).  The lower two plots have a title, and lose a bunch of space.

Is there a way to locate the title within the chart, top left or center?  Or center below with the legend could be ideal?  Also want the legend, but putting the title and the legend in the same real estate would work great too.  I can't find options for formatting the chart title?  Also if the legend could be placed at the top, that would accomplish the same thing.

Thanks!
[image: grafana dashboard]

Comment: Maybe I want to start looking here:   https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/     to make my desired changes.    We'll see..